# Sorting users by a field, not by ID

Tags: php

I basically do this now:

```
$users = get_users();
sort($users);
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<option>' . $user->companyname . '</option>';
}
```

Except the sort() function will sort by the ID. How can I change it to sort by my custom field companyname?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`get_users`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing orderby and order arguments in array.

`$args = array(
    'orderby'      => 'login',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
 );
get_users( $args );`

**orderby** - Sort by 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', 'post_count', 'include', or 'meta_value' (query must also contain a 'meta_key' - see [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)).

More details : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users